# OpenCV incompatible types in assignment

Tags: c, opencv, iplimage

my code is giving me this error and I don't understand what is the problem. 
Can someone explain to me what is the problem? Thank you!

This is the error code:

```
circleDetection.c:133: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘IplImage*’ to ‘IplImage* [(((long unsigned int)(((long int)cnt) - 1)) + 1u)]’
```

This is part of the file which gives the error:

```
void mainCircleDetection( IplImage *src )
{
    IplImage *img = cvCloneImage( src );

    if( !img ){
        printf("Image not loaded. EXITING...\n");
        exit( -1 );
    }

    IplImage *singleChannel = getSingleChannel( img );

    CvMemStorage *storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

    CvSeq *circlesStorage = findCircles( singleChannel );

    IplImage *imgCircles = drawCircles( img, circlesStorage );

    cvNamedWindow( "Detected circles", 1 );
    cvShowImage( "Detected circles", imgCircles );

    cvWaitKey( 0 );

    int cnt = circlesStorage->total;

    IplImage *circlesROI[ cnt ];

    circlesROI = getCircleROI( img, circlesStorage );

    cvDestroyAllWindows();

}
```

The line that gives the error is this one **circlesROI = getCircleROI( img, circlesStorage );**

And this is the function getCircleROI which is in another .c file

```
IplImage *getCircleROI( IplImage *src, CvSeq *circles){

    IplImage *img = cvCloneImage( src );

    int cnt = circles->total;

    IplImage *circlesROI[ circles->total ];

    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    {

        float *p = (float *)cvGetSeqElem( circles, i );
        CvPoint center = cvPoint( cvRound(p[0]), cvRound(p[1]) );
        int radius = (int)cvRound( p[2] );

        //void cvSetImageROI(IplImage* image, CvRect rect)
        //inline CvRect cvRect( int x, int y, int width, int height );
        cvSetImageROI( img, cvRect( center.x - radius, center.y - radius, 
            radius*2, radius*2) );

        //IplImage *mask = cvCreateImage( cvSize(radius*2, radius*2), img->depth, 1 );
        //cvZero( mask );

        //cvDrawCircle( mask, cvPoint( radius, radius), radius, cvScalarAll( 255 ), CV_FILLED );

        IplImage *res = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), img->depth, 3);
        IplImage *roi = getSingleChannel( res );
        //prepare the ROI image
        cvZero( roi );
        cvZero( res );

        //draw circle
        cvCircle( roi, cvPoint( radius, radius), radius, cvScalarAll( 255 ), -1, 8, 0 );

        //extract subimage
        cvAnd( img, img, res, roi );

        circlesROI[i] = cvCloneImage( res );

        cvNamedWindow("res", 1);
        cvShowImage("res", res);
        cvWaitKey( 0 );

    }

    cvDestroyAllWindows();
    cvReleaseImage( &img );

    return circlesROI;
}
```

Comment: circlesROI[i] = getCircleROI( img, circlesStorage );

Comment: `IplImage *circlesROI[ cnt ];` declares `circlesROI` as an array of `cnt` elements of type `IPLImage*`. You try to assign an `IplImage*` to it. Apart from the fact that arrays aren't assignable at all, that's the wrong type.

Comment: @DanielFischer I got the same impression. I am not familiar with IplImages, so would my advice still work?

Comment: @Shark Yes and no. It would fix that type error. But looking at the code of `getCircleROI`, that a) returns a `IplImage**` and b) that is the address of a local variable. So the brokenness is beyond the area our comments treated.

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, on a second thought i was 'afraid' that i have lead him into a even deeper rabbithole... but it looked like it would compile :)

oh well, glad i could help or w/e.

Comment: @Shark No deeper rabbithole, if `getCircleROI` had been sound and did what its signature says, your advice would have been good.

Comment: @Moirae As you may have learned from the comments, the code is broken beyond that line. To suggest fixes, we'd need to know what the intention behind the code is. Can you describe that?

Comment: Thanks Daniel and Shark for your good intentions. I would be too long to describe the topic of the thesis but the part connected to this code is this:

Comment: - getCircleROI function creates circular ROI mask for number of circles detected in the picture (I am now working on a picture that has 5 circles so it creates 5 different masks, each contains one of the circles. Circles are detected on image that shows 5 colorful balls). My idea was to store the masks in array and then to return that array to "main" and from there to use it as an argument for another function. 

Basically that's what this part of code should do. Maybe you have another way of doing this in mind? That would be helpful too.